# How to run Spock spec multiple times with different parameters?

Tags: gradle, groovy, spock, geb

I am writing automation test scripts using Groovy+Geb+Spock+Gradle framework. I have a spec called "UserProfilePageSpec" to check UI of user profile page and now I want to run it multiple times to check multiple users. I added randomness there so that each time the spec will select a random user in the list and navigate to the user profile page.

Also, I want to check 5 users per user type (which is a filter in homepage). So I need to click on each user type in the homepage, and then run the spec multiple times.

Sometimes I need to test just one user when there is no enough time to test multiple users in each type, so I kinda want to keep this spec to test for one user itself, does anyone have a good idea of implementing this? Thanks!

Here is a basic structure of "UserProfilePageSpec":

```
class UserProfilePageSpec {
    def setupSpec(){
        //login
        //select a random user
        //navigate to user profile page
    }
    def "test1"(){..}
    def "test2"(){..}
    def "test3"(){..}
    def "test4"(){..}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible in Spock, there are some open issues for it, e.g. https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/407 or https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/668

Depending on you usecase, you can use subclasses to simulate that.

```
abstract class UserProfilePageSpec {
    def setupSpec(){
        //login
        //select a random user
        //navigate to user profile page
    }

    abstract def getData()

    def "test1"(){..}
    def "test2"(){..}
    def "test3"(){..}
    def "test4"(){..}
}

class UserProfilePageVariation1Spec extends UserProfilePageSpec {

    def getData() { [username: 'foo', password: 'bar'] } 
}
```

Just create your variations as subclasses.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was worried that I couldn't express my question clearly, but your answer gives me exactly what I want! I ended up using inheritance, similar idea but with a non-abstract parent class. I created a function selectUserType() in UserProfilePageSpec and called it in setupSpec(), and created subclass for each user type and rewrite the selectUserType() function there.